# Why did I get all unit ones in this random walk test using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a python beginer and I was wondering why I got all unit ones in below script. I expected to get some integer numbers from 1-10.

```
import random

def random_walk(n):
    """Return coordinates after 'n' block random walk"""
    x, y = 0, 0
    for i in range(n):
        (dx, dy) = random.choice([(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)])
        x += dx
        y += dy
        return (x, y)

for i in range(5):
    walk = random_walk(10)
    print(walk, "Distance from home = ",
         abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))
```

Output:

```
(-1, 0) Distance from home =  1
(-1, 0) Distance from home =  1
(-1, 0) Distance from home =  1
(-1, 0) Distance from home =  1
(0, -1) Distance from home =  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line:

```
return (x, y)
```

should be outside of the loop:

```
import random

def random_walk(n):
    """Return coordinates after 'n' block random walk"""
    x, y = 0, 0
    for i in range(n):
        (dx, dy) = random.choice([(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)])
        x += dx
        y += dy
    return (x, y)

for i in range(5):
    walk = random_walk(10)
    print(walk, "Distance from home = ",
         abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))
```

Output:

```
(1, 1) Distance from home =  2
(-1, 1) Distance from home =  2
(-3, 3) Distance from home =  6
(0, -2) Distance from home =  2
(1, 3) Distance from home =  4
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out.